# Passing variables between functions inside class for OptionMenu

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, variables, tkinter

I'm having a problem with how to run some piece of code on some state of OptionMenu.

```
from tkinter import *

class Browser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.createUtility()
        return

    def createUtility(self):
        self.main_frame = Frame(bg="")
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.display_frame = Frame(width=50, height=50, bg="")
        self.display_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        options = ["Plants", "Wood", "Mushrooms", "Animals"]

        self.variable = StringVar()
        self.variable.set("Wood")
        self.change_menu = OptionMenu(self.main_frame, self.variable, *options, command=self.func)
        self.change_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.exit_button = Button(self.display_frame, text="Quit!", command=quit)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        if value == "Plants":
            #do some code
        elif value == "Wood":
            #do some code
        elif value == "Mushrooms":
            #do some code
        elif value == "Animals":
            #do some code 
        else:
            #do some code            
        return

    def func(self, value):
        return value
        #This value should be used for an if block in createUtility function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = Browser(Tk())
    mainloop()
```

I don't get errors, so that's good. I can click and select options in OptionMenu but nothing happens.

Comment: ***I don't get errors, so that's good.***... This is not always a good thing. At a glance I see some stuff I would change.

Comment: Yeah, I realised now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to say that not getting an error does not by default mean "good". There could be many reason for not getting an error and still have problems.

Now moving on to the code itself. You have a few problems.

1. Your method `func` is not doing anything useful here. Returning the event back to the menu item will result in nothing as it is being ignored by the `OptionMenu`. So here you would get no error because it is ignored.
2. Your `if/elif` statement will only run once and should fail with the error: `NameError: name 'value' is not defined`. Due to value never being defined in the `createUtility` method.
3. Your use of `return` is not needed in any of these places and in fact does nothing useful.
4. `b = Browser(Tk()) mainloop()` Is not a good approach. You need to be more explicit on your tkinter instance.
5. Small grievance but worth mentioning. Instead of doing `from tkinter import *` you should do `import tkinter as tk` and use the`tk.` prefix where needed. This will help prevent accidental overtiring of imports form tkinter.

Change it to something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Browser(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Browser(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        main_frame = tk.Frame(bg="")
        display_frame = tk.Frame(width=50, height=50, bg="")
        main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        display_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        options = ["Plants", "Wood", "Mushrooms", "Animals"]

        self.variable = tk.StringVar()
        self.variable.set("Wood")
        self.change_menu = tk.OptionMenu(main_frame, self.variable, *options, command=self.check_value)
        self.exit_button = tk.Button(display_frame, text="Quit!", command=quit)
        self.change_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def check_value(self, event):
        if event == "Plants":
            print(event)
        elif event == "Wood":
            print(event)
        elif event == "Mushrooms":
            print(event)
        elif event == "Animals":
            print(event)
        else:
            print("No match") 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Browser(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike - SMT. It works just how I wanted and thank you for the critic!